# how to solve NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! problem in Ionic 4 (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, odoo, ionic4, angular8

I have implemented a simple ionic application that has a page that calls a angular7-odooRpc service which you can find here [angular7-odoo-jsonrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-odoo-jsonrpc)
, but i'm facing this error when i call the constructor of OdooRPCService

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OdooRPCService -> HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OdooRPCService -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>   NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OdooRPCService -> HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OdooRPCService -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>       at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
>       at zone-evergreen.js:858
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)

In my app module file i imported HttpClientModule and i added it to imports array inside @ngModule

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular7-odoo-jsonrpc';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
        OdooRPCService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you add your app.module.ts code?

Comment: Done!, let me know if anything seems wrong

Comment: Have you checked you are importing the correct `HttpClient`? Sometimes it can autosuggest ones from other packages like `selenium-webdriver\HttpClient`? The one you want is `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @rtpHarry, Where do i have to import it, i'm not using it, OdooRPCService does.

Comment: Thats strange because I went to the [github repo](https://github.com/wbison3/angular7-odoo-jsonrpc) listed in the npm package, searched for `httpclient` and it came back with zero results, it doesn't exist in the OdooRPC... repo, so I assumed it must be somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @rtpHarry, Well, i did the same thing, and that why i added it literately everywhere, but it didn't solve the problem, (the strangest thing that the (how to use) section in the npm packages page they didn't talk about it at all),

Comment: @rtpHarry, I opened the "OdooRPCService.ts" file and i found that they imported HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: Sorry, my advice was all wrong up until now. I did search the results on Github, and it came up with zero code results but now I just tried it again and realised that it says on the code results tab "we cant search forked repos". I can see that the module clearly does use HttpClient.

Comment: @rtpHarry, no problem mate, do you have any other ideas that may help ?

Comment: glad you found some kind of workaround as I had hit a dead-end. I research the `@inject` and looked at the packages, but httpclient should have been inside common which was in the package.json, and i couldnt think of anything else to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution, i deleted all the files of the service and i created a new service (odooRPC.service.ts) and i copied the content of odoorpc.service.ts to odooRPC.service.ts (and that works perfect because they use the HttpClient located in node_modules under the project folder)

Comment: Can you share the code which you got working? Because I am having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the plan completely, because odoo 7 can't handle JsonRPC efficiently (I faced a lot of problems dealing with sessions and CORS), that's why i build a REST API in between and i used XMLRPC to connect odoo API with the REST API that i built

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that helped me,
The HttpClient object used in OdooRPCService.ts is located under node_modules inside OdooRPCService folder, and it's declared using dependency injection.
The solution is : i passed the httpclient object to the constructor of OdooRPCService from outside.

Comment: Adding a snippet of code would help the next person that has this issue.

Comment: I found a better solution, i deleted all the files of the service and i created a new service (odooRPC.service.ts) and i copied the content of odoorpc.service.ts to odooRPC.service.ts (and that works perfect because they use the HttpClient located in node_modules under the project folder)